# Angular MSAL (v2) login via redirect, redirecting 3 or more times before token acquisition

Tags: angular, azure-ad-msal, msal-angular

I have a Angular app (*v11.2.0*) that uses MSAL for authentication. I recently upgraded to v2 of the library (*@azure/msal-angular - ^2.1.1, @azure/msal-browser - ^2.22.0*), and it took some refactoring due to MSAL changes. It's mostly working as before with the exception of when it's authenticating a user and acquiring an authentication response: the process loops roughly 3 times before successfully getting an auth response, visibly refreshing the app each time. The approximate flow I'm seeing is as follows:

- **Loop 1**
- Navigate to app
- User not authenticated
- Handle redirect start
- Handle redirect promise called but there is no interaction in progress, returning null
- Handle redirect end
- Login start
- null authentication result received
- **Loop 2**
- Navigate to app
- User not authenticated
- Handle redirect start
- **Loop 3**
- Navigate to app
- User not authenticated
- Handle redirect start
- Info - in acquire token call
- Login success
- Handle redirect end
- Acquire token start
- Authentication result received

Authentication is initiated and handled in my app.component.ts:

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.msalBroadcastService.inProgress$
      .pipe(
         filter((status: InteractionStatus) => status === InteractionStatus.None)
      )
      .subscribe(async () => {
         if (!this.authenticated) {
            await this.logIn();
         }
      })

   this.msalService.handleRedirectObservable().subscribe({
      next: (result: AuthenticationResult) => {
         if (!this.msalService.instance.getActiveAccount() &&             
            this.msalService.instance.getAllAccounts().length > 0) {
               this.msalService.instance.setActiveAccount(result.account);
            }
         },
      error: (error) => console.log(error)
   });
}

async logIn() {
   await this.msalService.instance.loginRedirect({
      scopes: ['user.read', 'openid', 'profile'],
      redirectUri: AppConfig.settings.authenticationconfig.redirectUri
   });
};

get authenticated(): boolean {
   return this.msalService.instance.getActiveAccount() ? true : false;
}
```

Has anyone experienced a similar situation or have any understanding of what's causing this behaviour and how to resolve it?

Comment: I would love to know, because this started happening on one of my apps as well

Comment: @Venator Did you find any solution on this?

Comment: @NiAu Unfortunately I haven't found a solution yet, although I'm reassured that it's not an isolated incident. I'd love to find a fix!

Comment: @JoshuaTerrill there's been some progress! See the answers below; hopefully, they help solve the similar issues you've been experiencing.

Comment: @NiAu there's been some progress! See the answers below; hopefully, they help solve the similar issues you've been experiencing.

Answer (score 6):

For me, the final solution came in three parts.

The first piece of the puzzle was following @Ε Г И І И О's answer, making the following change within the ngOnInit() method of AppComponent -

Before:

```
// in app.component.ts        
this.msalService.handleRedirectObservable().subscribe({ 
   next: (result: AuthenticationResult) => {
      if (!this.msalService.instance.getActiveAccount() && this.msalService.instance.getAllAccounts().length > 0) {
         this.msalService.instance.setActiveAccount(result.account);
      }
   },
   error: (error) => console.log(error)
});
```

After:

```
// in app.component.ts       
this.msalBroadcastService.msalSubject$
   .pipe(
      filter(
         (msg: EventMessage) => msg.eventType === EventType.LOGIN_SUCCESS 
         || msg.eventType === EventType.SSO_SILENT_SUCCESS)
       ).subscribe((result: EventMessage) => {
          const payload = result.payload as AuthenticationResult;
          this.msalService.instance.setActiveAccount(payload.account);
    });
```

This stopped the looping behaviour but left the app in a hung state, with an interaction_in_progress BrowserAuthError. After some further digging, piece two was as follows -

Before:

```
// in app.module.ts
bootstrap: [AppComponent],
```

&

```
// in index.html
<body>
   <app-root></app-root>
</body>
```

After:

```
// in app.module.ts
bootstrap: [AppComponent, MsalRedirectComponent],
```

&

```
// in index.html
<body>
     <app-root></app-root>
     <app-redirect></app-redirect>
</body>
```

I had tried this previously with little success, but presumably, there's a tie-in to the first code change that works in conjunction with the second code change. The one final change I made was this - Before:

```
// in app.component.ts 
this.msalBroadcastService.inProgress$
   .pipe(
      filter((status: InteractionStatus) => status === InteractionStatus.None)
   )
   .subscribe(async () => {
     if (!this.authenticated) {
       await this.logIn();
     }
   });
```

After:

```
// in app.component.ts
this.msalBroadcastService.inProgress$
   .pipe(filter((status: InteractionStatus) => status === InteractionStatus.None)
   ,takeUntil(this._destroying$))
   .subscribe(async () => {
     if (!this.authenticated) {
       await this.logIn();
     }
   });
```

The app now behaves as desired, redirecting from the Microsoft login page and loading the app immediately - no more looping reloads!

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. Did you add method "this.msalBroadcastService.msalSubject$" in ngOnInit() method?

Comment: @ShankarNaru yes I did add this.msalBroadcastService.msalSubject$ into the ngOnInit() method of the AppComponent. I've updated the answer to make this clearer!

Answer (score 1):

MSAL is quite infamous for this type of issues. Hardly anyone gets it right the first time. I can't exactly say what's wrong with your code, but I'll share what I use. Maybe it'll give you some pointers.

Instead of `msalService.handleRedirectObservable()`, I listen on `msalBroadcastService.msalSubject$`, like so;

```
this.msalBroadcastService.msalSubject$
  .pipe(filter((msg: EventMessage) => msg.eventType === EventType.LOGIN_SUCCESS || msg.eventType === EventType.SSO_SILENT_SUCCESS))
  .subscribe((result: EventMessage) => {
    const payload = result.payload as AuthenticationResult;
    this.msalService.instance.setActiveAccount(payload.account);
  });
```